# Alert con JavaScript en JqueryMobile que muestre la informacion de un form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy intentando hacer un alert que aparezca al momento de presionar el boton de 'Enviar' y que muestre los datos que se introdujeron en la form, como el usuario, mail, sexo,etc. Sin embargo cuando hago click en el boton de enviar me redirecciona a otra pagina que dice "Not found" ¿Cual es mi error?

```js
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
   document.getElementById('Enviar').onclick = function(e){
       alert(document.getElementById("usuario").value);
       return false;
   }
}
 </script>
    <body>
        <div id="formulario1" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header"><h1>Formularios</h1>
                <a href="#formulario1" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="left">Home</a>
                <a href="#formulario2" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right">Siguiente</a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <form  data-ajax="false">
                    <label for="usuario">Usuario:<span>*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" name="text-basic" id="usuario" value="" placeholder="Usuario">
                    <label for="email">Correo:<span>*</span></label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
     <label for="password">Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" autocomplete="off">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                        <legend>Genero:</legend>
                        <label for="male">Masculino</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male">
                        <label for="female">Femenino</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female">
                        <label for="sd">Sin definir</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="sd" value="sd">
       
                    </fieldset>
                    
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                        <legend>Estado Civil:</legend>
                        <label for="soltero">Solter@</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="soltero" value="soltero">
                        <label for="casado">Casad@</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="casado" value="casado">
                        <label for="unionlibre">Union Libre</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="unionlibre" value="unionlibre">
                    </fieldset>
                  <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Enviar" data-theme="b"  id="Enviar" >
         


                    </form>
            
  
 
 
           
            </div>
```

Comment: Te sugiero que reemplazes el input type="submit" por button no por submit ...